# parsing date and apply query on fire data store

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have following collections in fire data store and want to apply following query on collection before fetching it.

```
**.whereEqualTo("order_execution_time", today's date)**

[
  {
    "symbol": "HINDUNILVR22MAR2000PE",
    "trade_type": "buy",
    "quantity": 300,
    "price": 4.00,
    "order_execution_time": "2022-03-18T09:44:45"
  },
  
  {
    "symbol": "ASIANPAINT22MAR2500PE",
    "trade_type": "buy",
    "quantity": 300,
    "price": 1.00,
    "order_execution_time": "2022-03-21T09:35:42"
  },
  {
    "symbol": "HINDUNILVR22MAR2000PE",
    "trade_type": "buy",
    "quantity": 300,
    "price": 4.00,
    "order_execution_time": "2022-03-21T09:44:43"
  },
  
  {
    "symbol": "HINDUNILVR22MAR2000PE",
    "trade_type": "buy",
    "quantity": 300,
    "price": 4.00,
    "order_execution_time": "2022-03-22T09:44:45"
  }
]
```

What is the most correct to to filter these in Java adroid.

Answer (score 1):

A classical approach would be to dernomalize your data and add to each Firestore document a `order_execution_date` field that would only contain the date, as follows:

```
[
  {
    "symbol": "HINDUNILVR22MAR2000PE",
    "trade_type": "buy",
    "quantity": 300,
    "price": 4.00,
    "order_execution_time": "2022-03-18T09:44:45"
  },
  
  {
    "symbol": "ASIANPAINT22MAR2500PE",
    "trade_type": "buy",
    "quantity": 300,
    "price": 1.00,
    "order_execution_time": "2022-03-21T09:35:42"
    "order_execution_date": "2022-03-21"
  },
  // ...
]
```

This way you can easily query with today's date in format `YYYY-MM-DD`.